# Compiled vs. Interpreted Languages

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the difference. I've found a lot of explanations online, but they tend towards the abstract differences rather than the practical implications.

Most of my programming experiences has been with CPython (dynamic, interpreted), and Java (static, compiled). However, I understand that there are other kinds of interpreted and compiled languages. Aside from the fact that executable files can be distributed from programs written in compiled languages, are there any advantages/disadvantages to each type? Oftentimes, I hear people arguing that interpreted languages can be used interactively, but I believe that compiled languages can have interactive implementations as well, correct?

Comment: You chose exactly the worst languages for this comparison. Both are bytecompiled. The only real difference between them is the JITer, and even Python has a partial one (psyco).

Comment: A good example of an interactive compiled language is Clojure - everything is fully compiled (first to the JVM then to native code via the JIT). However a lot of the recompilation happens dynamically, and development is often done in an interactive REPL shell where you can evaluate any function you want in the running environment.

Comment: Standard ML is another interactive compiled language; the built-in compiler issues real native machine code too.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zappldev/zappldev_85.htm

Comment: Just because OP came up with two languages as examples doesn't make the question *about* either of them. Removed those tags. I could add the `language-agnostic` tag, but that's already implicit in `compiler-construction` and `programming-languages`.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

A compiled language is one where the program, once compiled, is expressed in the instructions of the target machine. For example, an addition "+" operation in your source code could be translated directly to the "ADD" instruction in machine code.

An interpreted language is one where the instructions are not directly executed by the target machine, but instead read and executed by some other program (which normally *is* written in the language of the native machine). For example, the same "+" operation would be recognised by the interpreter at run time, which would then call its own "add(a,b)" function with the appropriate arguments, which would then execute the machine code "ADD" instruction.

You can do anything that you can do in an interpreted language in a compiled language and vice-versa - they are both Turing complete. Both however have advantages and disadvantages for implementation and use.

I'm going to completely generalise (purists forgive me!) but, roughly, here are the advantages of compiled languages:

- Faster performance by directly using the native code of the target machine
- Opportunity to apply quite powerful optimisations during the compile stage

And here are the advantages of interpreted languages:

- Easier to implement (writing good compilers is very hard!!)
- No need to run a compilation stage: can execute code directly "on the fly"
- Can be more convenient for dynamic languages

Note that modern techniques such as bytecode compilation add some extra complexity - what happens here is that the compiler targets a "virtual machine" which is not the same as the underlying hardware. These virtual machine instructions can then be compiled again at a later stage to get native code (e.g. as done by the Java JVM JIT compiler).

Comment: Not all compiled languages need a slow compilation stage.  Serious Common Lisp implementations are compilers, and they often don't bother with an interpreter, preferring to just compile real fast on the fly.  On the other hand, Java does need a compilation step, and it usually is visible.

Comment: @David completely agree! As I said I was generalising somewhat :-) I use Clojure quite a bit, which compiles on the fly (to the JVM) in exactly the same way.

Comment: @mikera great answer. Just one clarification regarding your point for interpreter being a more viable choice for dynamic languages. Why is implementing interpreter easy for dynamic languages like JavaScript?

Comment: @mikera If the interpreter does the following:
1- takes the non-native code.
2- calls the appropriate function on that code which is, not surprisingly, calls the appropriate native function.

On the other hand the JIT compilation does the following:
1- takes the non-native code.
2- compiles it to an intermediate language which is, as I imagine, translated to the native machine code somehow and executed.

then what's real advantages of the JIT compilation over interpreting?

Comment: @Kareem: the JIT compiler only does 1) and 2) *once* - after that it is native code all the way. The interpreter needs to do both 1) and 2) every time the code is called (which may be many, many times...). So over time, the JIT compiler wins by a long margin.

Comment: @mikera Isn't bytecode translated into machine code during execution? If not, then when exactly is it translated to machine code?

Comment: Yes bytecode is translated to machine code *at some point* during the overall program execution (as opposed to before program execution, as is the case with a traditional compiler). But a given piece of code might be executed 10 million+ times during overall program execution. It (probably) only gets compiled *once* from bytecode to machine code. Hence the runtime overhead of JIT is small, and can be ignored for long-running programs. After the JIT compiler has finished doing its job, you will effectively be running pure machine code all the way.

Comment: This is actually a false dichotomy. There is nothing intrinsic to a language that makes it compiled our interpreted. It is nothing more than a widely held misconception. Many languages have both implementations and all languages can have either.

Comment: @mmachenry it is not a false dichotomy. "programming language" includes both design and implementation. While in an *theoretical sense* a given language definition can be both compiled and interpreted, in *real world practice* there are considerable differences in implementation. Nobody has yet solved how to effectively compile certain language constructs, for example - it is an open research problem.

Comment: @mikera Indeed, it is. There are benefits to compiling and there are benefits to interpreting. Just because compiler technology is developing to improve on certain languages features don't mean we can say anything about the benefits of compiling a language with that feature. Conflating language and implementation causes us to have false understandings of choosing compilation or interpretation for an implementation. For example your comment "[interpreters] Can be more convenient for dynamic languages"

Comment: Add basic syntax checking of the whole program to the list for compilers.

Comment: So basically, with interpreted languages, there is a layer between the machine and the code you write, whereas a compiled language does not have a layer of indirection.?

Comment: `Opportunity to apply quite powerful optimizations during the compile stage` So does this mean that the same source file can produce different object files depending on how it is compiled? I.e. the statements in a particular source file and the machine instructions from a resulting compilation do not necessarily have a one-to-one relationship, but perhaps a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: The interpreter itself is compiled. Right? Because at the very end, you need machine code. Right?

Answer (score 109):

A language itself is neither compiled nor interpreted, only a specific implementation of a language is.  Java is a perfect example.  There is a bytecode-based platform (the JVM), a native compiler (gcj) and an interpeter for a superset of Java (bsh).  So what is Java now? Bytecode-compiled, native-compiled or interpreted?

Other languages, which are compiled as well as interpreted, are Scala, Haskell or Ocaml.  Each of these languages has an interactive interpreter, as well as a compiler to byte-code or native machine code.

So generally categorizing languages by "compiled" and "interpreted" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I agree. Or let's say: There are native compilers (creating machine code for the CPU to eat), and not-so-native-compilers (creating tokenized stuff, i.e. intermediate code, that some just-in-time compiler compiles to machine code before (or during) runtime ONCE), and there are "real" non-compilers that never produce machine code and never let the CPU run the code. The latter are interpreters.

Today, native compilers which directly produce machine (CPU) code at compile-time are becoming more and more rare. Delphi/Codegear is one of the best survivors.

Answer (score 65):

Start thinking in terms of a: **blast from the past**

Once upon a time, long long ago, there lived in the land of computing
interpreters and compilers. All kinds of fuss ensued over the merits of
one over the other. The general opinion *at that time* was something along the lines of:

- Interpreter: Fast to develop (edit and run). Slow to execute because each statement had to be interpreted into
  machine code every time it was executed (think of what this meant for a loop executed thousands of times).
- Compiler: Slow to develop (edit, compile, link and run. The compile/link steps could take serious time). Fast
  to execute. The whole program was already in native machine code.

A one or two order of magnitude difference in the runtime
performance existed between an interpreted program and a compiled program. Other distinguishing 
points, run-time mutability of the code for example, were also of some interest but the major
distinction revolved around the run-time performance issues.

Today the landscape has evolved to such an extent that the compiled/interpreted distinction is 
pretty much irrelevant. Many
compiled languages call upon run-time services that are not
completely machine code based. Also, most interpreted languages are "compiled" into byte-code
before execution. Byte-code interpreters can be very efficient and rival some compiler generated
code from an execution speed point of view.

The classic difference is that compilers generated native machine code, interpreters read source code and
generated machine code on the fly using some sort of run-time system. 
Today there are very few classic interpreters left - almost all of them
compile into byte-code (or some other semi-compiled state) which then runs on a virtual "machine".

Answer (score 28):

The extreme and simple cases:

- A compiler will produce a binary executable in the target machine's native executable format. This binary file contains all required resources except for system libraries; it's ready to run with no further preparation and processing and it runs like lightning because the code is the native code for the CPU on the target machine.
- An interpreter will present the user with a prompt in a loop where he can enter statements or code, and upon hitting `RUN` or the equivalent the interpreter will examine, scan, parse and interpretatively execute each line until the program runs to a stopping point or an error. Because each line is treated on its own and the interpreter doesn't "learn" anything from having seen the line before, the effort of converting human-readable language to machine instructions is incurred every time for every line, so it's dog slow. On the bright side, the user can inspect and otherwise interact with his program in all kinds of ways: Changing variables, changing code, running in trace or debug modes... whatever.

With those out of the way, let me explain that life ain't so simple any more. For instance,

- Many interpreters will pre-compile the code they're given so the translation step doesn't have to be repeated again and again.
- Some compilers compile not to CPU-specific machine instructions but to bytecode, a kind of artificial machine code for a ficticious machine. This makes the compiled program a bit more portable, but requires a bytecode interpreter on every target system.
- The bytecode interpreters (I'm looking at Java here) recently tend to re-compile the bytecode they get for the CPU of the target section just before execution (called JIT). To save time, this is often only done for code that runs often (hotspots).
- Some systems that look and act like interpreters (Clojure, for instance) compile any code they get, immediately, but allow interactive access to the program's environment. That's basically the convenience of interpreters with the speed of binary compilation.
- Some compilers don't really compile, they just pre-digest and compress code. I heard a while back that's how Perl works. So sometimes the compiler is just doing a bit of the work and most of it is still interpretation.

In the end, these days, interpreting vs. compiling is a trade-off, with time spent (once) compiling often being rewarded by better runtime performance, but an interpretative environment giving more opportunities for interaction. Compiling vs. interpreting is mostly a matter of how the work of "understanding" the program is divided up between different processes, and the line is a bit blurry these days as languages and products try to offer the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 27):

From http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-compiled-and-interpreted-programming-languages

> There is no difference, because “compiled programming language” and
>   “interpreted programming language” aren’t meaningful concepts. Any
>   programming language, and I really mean any, can be interpreted or
>   compiled. Thus, interpretation and compilation are implementation
>   techniques, not attributes of languages.
>
> Interpretation is a technique whereby another program, the
>   interpreter, performs operations on behalf of the program being
>   interpreted in order to run it. If you can imagine reading a program
>   and doing what it says to do step-by-step, say on a piece of scratch
>   paper, that’s just what an interpreter does as well. A common reason
>   to interpret a program is that interpreters are relatively easy to
>   write. Another reason is that an interpreter can monitor what a
>   program tries to do as it runs, to enforce a policy, say, for
>   security.
>
> Compilation is a technique whereby a program written in one language
>   (the “source language”) is translated into a program in another
>   language (the “object language”), which hopefully means the same thing
>   as the original program. While doing the translation, it is common for
>   the compiler to also try to transform the program in ways that will
>   make the object program faster (without changing its meaning!). A
>   common reason to compile a program is that there’s some good way to
>   run programs in the object language quickly and without the overhead
>   of interpreting the source language along the way.
>
> You may have guessed, based on the above definitions, that these two
>   implementation techniques are not mutually exclusive, and may even be
>   complementary. Traditionally, the object language of a compiler was
>   machine code or something similar, which refers to any number of
>   programming languages understood by particular computer CPUs. The
>   machine code would then run “on the metal” (though one might see, if
>   one looks closely enough, that the “metal” works a lot like an
>   interpreter). Today, however, it’s very common to use a compiler to
>   generate object code that is meant to be interpreted—for example, this
>   is how Java used to (and sometimes still does) work. There are
>   compilers that translate other languages to JavaScript, which is then
>   often run in a web browser, which might interpret the JavaScript, or
>   compile it a virtual machine or native code. We also have interpreters
>   for machine code, which can be used to emulate one kind of hardware on
>   another. Or, one might use a compiler to generate object code that is
>   then the source code for another compiler, which might even compile
>   code in memory just in time for it to run, which in turn . . . you get
>   the idea. There are many ways to combine these concepts.

Comment: Can you fix this sentence: "There are compilers that translate other languages to JavaScript, which is then often run in a web browser, which might interpret the JavaScript, or compile it a virtual machine or native code."

Comment: Nailed it. Another common mistake is to attribute the usefulness of a language to its existing APIs.

Answer (score 11):

The biggest advantage of interpreted source code over compiled source code is **PORTABILITY**.

If your source code is compiled, you need to compile a different executable for each type of processor and/or platform that you want your program to run on (e.g. one for Windows x86, one for Windows x64, one for Linux x64, and so on). Furthermore, unless your code is completely standards compliant and does not use any platform-specific functions/libraries, you will actually need to write and maintain multiple code bases!

If your source code is interpreted, you only need to write it once and it can be interpreted and executed by an appropriate interpreter on any platform! It's **portable**! Note that an interpreter itself is an executable program that *is* written and compiled for a specific platform.

An advantage of compiled code is that it **hides the source code** from the end user (which might be **intellectual property**) because instead of deploying the original human-readable source code, you deploy an obscure binary executable file.

Comment: on this terms java can't be considered a "compiled language", but it's compile phase give the advantages of compiling (type checking, early error detection, etc.), and produce bytecode that can be run on every OS, with a Java virtual machine provided.

Answer (score 8):

A compiler and an interpreter do the same job: translating a programming language to another pgoramming language, usually closer to the hardware, often direct executable machine code.

Traditionally, "compiled" means that this translation happens all in one go, is done by a developer, and the resulting executable is distributed to users. Pure example: C++.
Compilation usually takes pretty long and tries to do lots of expensive optmization so that the resulting executable runs faster. End users don't have the tools and knowledge to compile stuff themselves, and the executable often has to run on a variety of hardware, so you can't do many hardware-specific optimizations. During development, the separate compilation step means a longer feedback cycle.

Traditionally, "interpreted" means that the translation happens "on the fly", when the user wants to run the program. Pure example: vanilla PHP. A naive interpreter has to parse and translate every piece of code every time it runs, which makes it very slow. It can't do complex, costly optimizations because they'd take longer than the time saved in execution. But it can fully use the capabilities of the hardware it runs on. The lack of a separrate compilation step reduces feedback time during development.

But nowadays "compiled vs. interpreted" is not a black-or-white issue, there are shades in between. Naive, simple interpreters are pretty much extinct. Many languages use a two-step process where the high-level code is translated to a platform-independant bytecode (which is much faster to interpret). Then you have "just in time compilers" which compile code at most once per program run, sometimes cache results, and even intelligently decide to interpret code that's run rarely, and do powerful optimizations for code that runs a lot. During development, debuggers are capable of switching code inside a running program even for traditionally compiled languages.

Comment: However, C++'s compilation model is inherited from C and was designed without consideration of features such as templates.  This awkwardness contributes to C++'s long compile times much more than any other factor – and makes it a poor example.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the biggest misunderstood things in computer science as I guess.
Because interpretation and compilation are completely two different things, which we can't compare in this way.

### **The compilation is the process of translating one language into another language. There are few types of compilations.**

- Compiling - Translate high-level language into machine/byte code (ex: C/C++/Java)
- Transpiling - Translate high-level language into another high-level language (ex: TypeScript)

### **Interpretation is the process of actually executing the program. This may happen in few different ways.**

- Machine level interpretation - This interpretation happens to the code which is compiled into machine code. Instructions are directly interpreted by the processor. Programming languages like C/C++ generate machine code, which is executable by the processor. So the processor can directly execute these instructions.
- Virtual machine level interpretation - This interpretation happens to the code which is not compiled into the machine level (processor support) code, but into some intermediate-level code. This execution is done by another software, which is executed by the processor. At this time actually processor doesn't see our application. It just executing the virtual machine, which is executing our application. Programming languages like Java, Python, C# generate a byte code, which is executable by the virtual interpreter/machine.

So at the end of the day what we have to understand is, ***all the programming languages in the world should be interpreted at some time.*** It may be done by a processor(hardware) or a virtual machine.

The compilation is just the process of bringing the high-level code we write that is human-understandable into some hardware/software machine-understandable level.

These are completely two different things, which we can't compare. But that terminology is pretty much good to teach beginners how programming languages work.

PS: 
Some programming languages like Java have a hybrid approach to do this. First, compile the high-level code into byte code which is virtual-machine readable. And on the fly, a component called the JIT compiler compiles byte-code into machine code. Specifically, code lines that are executed again and again many times are get translated into the machine language, which makes the interpretation process much faster. Because hardware processor is always much faster than virtual interpreter/processor.

[How Java JIT compiler works](https://medium.com/runtimeerror/java-jit-compiler-c538e5e06a2)

Answer (score 5):

First, a clarification, Java is not fully static-compiled and linked in the way C++. It is compiled into bytecode, which is then interpreted by a JVM. The JVM can go and do just-in-time compilation to the native machine language, but doesn't have to do it.

More to the point: I think interactivity is the main practical difference. Since everything is interpreted, you can take a small excerpt of code, parse and run it against the current state of the environment. Thus, if you had already executed code that initialized a variable, you would have access to that variable, etc. It really lends itself way to things like the functional style.

Interpretation, however, costs a lot, especially when you have a large system with a lot of references and context. By definition, it is wasteful because identical code may have to be interpreted and optimized twice (although most runtimes have some caching and optimizations for that). Still, you pay a runtime cost and often need a runtime environment. You are also less likely to see complex interprocedural optimizations because at present their performance is not sufficiently interactive.

Therefore, for large systems that are not going to change much, and for certain languages, it makes more sense to precompile and prelink everything, do all the optimizations that you can do. This ends up with a very lean runtime that is already optimized for the target machine.

As for generating executables, that has little to do with it, IMHO. You can often create an executable from a compiled language. But you can also create an executable from an interpreted language, except that the interpreter and runtime is already packaged in the exectuable and hidden from you. This means that you generally still pay the runtime costs (although I am sure that for some language there are ways to translate everything to a tree executable).

I disagree that all languages could be made interactive. Certain languages, like C, are so tied to the machine and the entire link structure that I'm not sure you can build a meaningful fully-fledged interactive version

Comment: C is not really tied to a "machine".  The syntax and semantics of C are rather simple.  It shouldn't be particularly difficult to implement a C-interpreter, only very time-consuming (because the standard library has to be implemented as well).  And btw, Java can be compiled into native machine code (using gcj).

Comment: @lunaryorn: I disagree about GCJ. GCJ merely gives you an executable based environment. "Compiled applications are linked with the GCJ runtime, libgcj, which provides the core class libraries, a garbage collector, and a bytecode interpreter"

Comment: GCJ *does* produce native machine code, and not just an executable environment with embedded interpreter and bytecode.   libgcj provides a bytecode interpreter to support calls from native code into Java bytecode, not to interpret the compiled program.  If libgcj did not provide a bytecode interpreter, GCJ would not comply to the Java spec.

Comment: @lunaryorn: Ah. Ok, I appreciate the clarification and stand corrected. We primarily use Java in a windows environment so I haven't tried gcj in years.

Comment: [You](http://www.softintegration.com/) [can](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) [interpret](http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC) [C](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/16526/download.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The Python Book © 2015 Imagine Publishing Ltd, simply distunguishes the difference by the following hint mentioned in page 10 as:

> An interpreted language such as Python is one where the source code is converted to machine code and then executed each time the program runs. This is different from a compiled language such as C, where the source code is only converted to machine code once – the resulting machine code is then executed each time the program runs.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather difficult to give a practical answer because the difference is about the language definition itself. It's possible to build an interpreter for every compiled language, but it's not possible to build an compiler for every interpreted language. It's very much about the formal definition of a language. So that theoretical informatics stuff noboby likes at university.

Comment: Surely you can build a compiler for an interpreted language, but the compiled machine-code is itself a mirror of the runtime.

Comment: Not just a mirror of the runtime. E.g. imagine constructs like `eval()` in many scripting languages: You'd actually have to include the *compiler* in the resulting program, not just the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Compile is the process of creating an executable program from code written in a compiled programming language. Compiling allows the computer to run and understand the program without the need of the programming software used to create it. When a program is compiled it is often compiled for a specific platform (e.g. IBM platform) that works with IBM compatible computers, but not other platforms (e.g. Apple platform).
The first compiler was developed by Grace Hopper while working on the Harvard Mark I computer. Today, most high-level languages will include their own compiler or have toolkits available that can be used to compile the program. A good example of a compiler used with Java is Eclipse and an example of a compiler used with C and C++ is the gcc command. Depending on how big the program is it should take a few seconds or minutes to compile and if no errors are encountered while being compiled an executable file is created.check this information

Answer (score 1):

Short (un-precise) definition:

**Compiled language:** Entire program is translated to machine code at once, then the machine code is run by the CPU.

**Interpreted language:** Program is read line-by-line and as soon as a line is read the machine instructions for that line are executed by the CPU.

But really, few languages these days are purely compiled or purely interpreted, it often is a mix. For a more detailed description with pictures, see this thread:

[What is the difference between compilation and interpretation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306893/what-is-the-difference-between-compilation-and-interpretation/24308305#24308305)

Or my later blog post:

https://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/the-difference-between-compiler-and-interpreter/