# How to use sublimeREPL to get C++ user input in Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I  installed Sublime Text 3 and  sublimeREPL but I don't understand how  to get C++ user input from programs.

It's been three days and I have not found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SublimeREPL is only for interpreted languages that support REPLs — "Read-Eval-Print-Loop" — such as Perl, Python, Ruby, R, Scala, Lisp, Haskell, etc.

C++ is a compiled language that does not have a REPL, and so is unsupported by SublimeREPL.

You'll need to run your compiled C++ program via an external shell in order to get user input.

See this question ([Compiled vs. Interpreted Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265357)) for the differences between compiled and interpreted languages. Read at least the first several answers, as the terms "compiled" and "interpreted" are not very good descriptors, and are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks@MattDMo, please tell me how to install that external shell

Comment: It's just the regular command line that already comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks,I dont know how exactly this can be installed, could u please share it or share any link. thanks

Comment: @SaleemRaza do you have access to Google? `ubuntu command line` should be informative. I'm not going to hold your hand through this if you don't at least **try** to help yourself.

Comment: I have tried, and install but it doesnt work in sublime,

Comment: "I have tried, and install but it doesnt work in sublime" It works, quite nicely, but involves some research. It's well documented.