# Python: Benefits of compiling into BYTECODE over compiling into Machine Code?

Tags: python, c

Python is interpreted not compiled, that means each line of source code is compiled line by line to BYTECODE. (Is the term "compiled" that i just used is correct ?)

who does this conversion from source code to BYTECODE ?(Is that Interpreter program ?)....(In low level languages like C, i know the source code is compiled at a time by a compiler.)

What is the difference between BYTECODE and Machine CODE ? (is the processing of bytecode changes with language?

If in C , source code is also compiled into machine code and then run. similarly in python , source code is also interpretted /compiled to BYTECODE, and then changed into machine code and then run , THEN WHAT IS THE  benefit of using interpreter in python?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-byte-code-and-machine-code-and-what-are-its-advantages

gives a good overview for difference between byte code and machine code. The main advantage is portability of code across different environments from the perspective of the developer.

You can find quite a few resources online for the pros and cons of compiled languages vs interpreted languages

[Compiled vs. Interpreted Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265357/compiled-vs-interpreted-languages)